# Use RobustScaler in a LSTM with Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, scaling

I want to scale time series data with outliers and use it in a LSTM model with Keras.

My code for the scaling is:

```
# Train Data
scaler = RobustScaler().fit(train)
train = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(train))
train = train.values
# Test Data
test = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(test))
test = test.values
```

Afterwards, I put the data into 3D format for Keras:

```
# split a multivariate sequence into samples
def split_sequences(sequences, n_steps):
  X, y = list(), list()
  for i in range(len(sequences)):
    # find the end of this pattern
    end_ix = i + n_steps
    # check if we are beyond the dataset
    if end_ix > len(sequences)-1:
      break
    # gather input and output parts of the pattern
    seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :], sequences[end_ix, :12]
    X.append(seq_x)
    y.append(seq_y)
  return np.array(X), np.array(y)

# choose a number of time steps
n_steps = 30

# convert into train input/output
X_trai, y_trai = split_sequences(train, n_steps)
print(X_trai.shape, y_trai.shape)

# convert into test input/output
X_test, y_test = split_sequences(test, n_steps)
print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
```

The training and prediction works well, however, I am not able to inverse transform the predicted y data of the test dataset.

My questions:

1. Is the above scaling method correct?
2. If yes, How can I regain the original scale of my y_hat predictions to compare it with the original y test dataset?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to this, but this is the way I've been able to do it successfully:

1. Create a transformer for the various features
2. Create a transformer for the target (i.e., the thing you are predicting)
3. Transform the data
4. Create the dataset
5. Create and run the model
6. Use the "inverse_transform" function to bring the data back to its original form

Here is an example of what I am trying to describe, below.

> Note: This does cause a "setting with copy warning" that I need to resolve as in "See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)"

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
f_columns = ['A',
             'B',
             'C',
             'D'
             ]

f_transformer = RobustScaler()
target_transformer = RobustScaler()

f_transformer = f_transformer.fit(train[f_columns].to_numpy())
target_transformer = target_transformer.fit(train[['target']])

train.loc[:, f_columns] = f_transformer.transform(train[f_columns].to_numpy()).copy()
train['target'] = DA_transformer.transform(train[['target']]).copy()
```

#Steps 4 and 5

```
y_trai_inv = target_transformer.inverse_transform(y_trai.reshape(1, -1))
y_test_inv = target_transformer.inverse_transform(y_test.reshape(1, -1))
y_pred_inv = target_transformer.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```